# Can only read Excel file when it is actually open in Ms Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am using the following code to open an excel file (XLS) and populate a `DataTable` with the first worksheet:

```
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", filename);

OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
connExcel.Open();
DataTable dtExcelSchema;
dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
connExcel.Close();

var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + SheetName + "]", connectionString);
var ds = new DataSet();
int count = 0;

adapter.Fill(ds, SheetName);

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

It works only when the file is already open in Ms Excel. Why could that be?

If the file is not open, I get an error message (on line `connExcel.Open`): `External table is not in the expected format.`

Comment: Try putting a $ after the sheet name (between the " and the ]" see if that works.

Comment: What's your `fileName`? Does that need to include the address perhaps? (i.e. `fileName = "C:\Users\myself\Docs\mySheet.xlsx"`)

Comment: @CharlesMay It works when Excel is open, so that cannot be the problem. Anyway the error happens before it gets to that part of the code.

Comment: @BruceWayne File name is OK, I checked it.

Comment: This wasn't by any chance a text file renamed to .xls was it? I asked because another [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612989/cant-connect-to-excel-file-unless-file-is-already-open) found that to be the issue.

Comment: You fellows are not reading the question! I reiterate, this works when MsExcel is open, it is only when Ms Excel is closed that it does not work. It's wierd, but that's what's happening.

Comment: Maybe it's the driver.  I notice it doesn't match here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/excel-97-2003-xls-files-with-ace-oledb-120/. Can you test a change it from Jet to `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;`

Comment: @Hambone I tried that, still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem and accordingly to this site, many developers are struggling for the same:

-[When I try read Excel with OLE DB all values are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033034/when-i-try-read-excel-with-ole-db-all-values-are-empty)

-[Can't connect to excel file unless file is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612989/cant-connect-to-excel-file-unless-file-is-already-open)

Actually I'm using the classic connection string (note that I'm trying to read a 97/2003 file):

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = " + GetFilename(filename) + "; Extended Properties ='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'
```

but the file can be read properly only if:

- Is open in Excel **or** even in Word! (the file of course appears corrupted and unreadable, but then the OleDb procedure can read every line of the file), I didn't try with other Office apps
- The file is not in read-only mode

I also tried to lock the file manually or to open it with other non-office applications, but the result is not the same. If I follow the two previous rules (file opened in Word or Excel in not read-only mode) I can see all the cells, otherwise it seems the first **column** is ignored completely (so F2 became F1, F3 became F2,... and F6, the last one, should became F5 otherwise it throws and out-of-index error).

In order to keep compatibility with OleDb without using 3rd parties libraries I found a very stupid workaround using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly.

```
Excel.Application _app = new Excel.Application();
var workbooks = _app.Workbooks;
workbooks.Open(_filename);

// OleDb Connection
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionOleDb))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;

                    cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}$]", tableName);
OleDbDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    int i = 0;
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        //Here I read through all Excel rows
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception E)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error!\n" + E.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();

                    workbooks.Close();
                    if (workbooks != null)
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
                    _app.Quit();
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_app);
                }
            }
```

Essentially the first 3 lines run an Excel instance that lasts exactly the time needed to OleDb to perform its tasks.
The last 4 lines, inside the finally block, let the Excel instance to be closed correctly, immediately after the task and avoid ghost Excel processes.

I repeat it's a very stupid workaround that also requires a 1,5 MB dll (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll) to be added to the project.
Anyway seems impossible that OleDb cannot manage by itself the missing data...

Comment: Up-voted for the workaround, but cannot accept the answer until there is a solution

Comment: Of course I will not give up! :-) What I just found is that the original file generator influence a lot the final result: official Excel applications make reliable files and easy to read, 3rd parties apps make the things more tricky

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. If the file was open the read was ok but if the file was closed... some thing was strange... in my case I received strange data from columns and values.. Debugging I found the name of the first sheet and was strange ["xls _xlnm#_FilterDatabase"] looking on the internet I found that's a name of hidden sheet and a trick to avoid read this sheet ([HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034296/multi-sheet-import-with-oledb-netting-xlnm-filterdatabase-as-sheet-names)) and so I've implemented a method:

```
private string getFirstVisibileSheet(DataTable dtSheet, int index = 0)
{
    string sheetName = String.Empty;
    if (dtSheet.Rows.Count >= (index + 1))
    {
        sheetName = dtSheet.Rows[index]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        if (sheetName.Contains("FilterDatabase"))
        {
            return getFirstVisibileSheet(dtSheet, ++index);
        }
    }
    return sheetName;
}
```

To me worked very well.

My complete example code is:

```
string excelFilePath = String.Empty;
string stringConnection = String.Empty;

using (OpenFileDialog openExcelDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    openExcelDialog.Filter = "Excel 2007 (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Excel 2003 (*.xls)|*.xls";
    openExcelDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
    openExcelDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
    DialogResult windowsResult = openExcelDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (windowsResult != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return;
    }

    excelFilePath = openExcelDialog.FileName;
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
        try
        {
            if (!excelFilePath.Equals(String.Empty))
            {
                stringConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFilePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0; HDR=YES;';";
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(stringConnection))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;

                    DataTable dtSheet = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

                    string sheetName = getFirstVisibileSheet(dtSheet);

                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
                    dt.TableName = sheetName;

                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    cmd = null;
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }

            //Read and Use my DT
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                //On my case I need data on first and second Columns
                if ((row.ItemArray.Count() < 2) ||
                    (row[0] == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row[0].ToString()))
                    ||
                    (row[1] == null ||String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row[1].ToString())))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                //Get the number from the first COL
                int colOneNumber = 0;
                Int32.TryParse(row[0].ToString(), out colOneNumber);

                //Get the string from the second COL
                string colTwoString = row[1].ToString();

                //Get the string from third COL if is a file path valid
                string colThree = (row.ItemArray.Count() >= 3 
                                && !row.IsNull(2) 
                                && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row[2].ToString()) 
                                && File.Exists(row[2].ToString())
                                ) ? row[2].ToString() : String.Empty;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Import error.\n" + ex.Message, "::ERROR::", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}

private string getFirstVisibileSheet(DataTable dtSheet, int index = 0)
{
    string sheetName = String.Empty;
    if (dtSheet.Rows.Count >= (index + 1))
    {
        sheetName = dtSheet.Rows[index]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        if (sheetName.Contains("FilterDatabase"))
        {
            return getFirstVisibileSheet(dtSheet, ++index);
        }
    }
    return sheetName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it failing on `ToString()`, like here?
[Error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332443/error-is-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)

Does `Convert.ToString()` fix anything?

Comment: It is failing on `connExcel.Open`